# Url Encoding an array

Tags: c#, url, servicestack

This might seem dirty but it's for documentation purposes I swear!

I am accessing my services using `GET`s in my documentation so people can try things out without needing to get too complicated.

Appending `x-http-method-override=POST` to the URL forces the server to take a `GET` as a `POST`

This is all good except when I need to `POST` an array of objects. This would be simple in a standard POST but today I have a new bread of nightmare.

The expected `POST` looks like:

```
{"name":"String","slug":"String","start":"String","end":"String","id":"String","artists":[{"id":"String","name":"String","slug":"String"}],"locationId":"String"}
```

As you can see there is an array of artists up in here.

I have tried to do the following:

```
model/listing?start=10:10&end=12:30&artists[0].name=wayne&artists[0].id=artists-289&locationid=locations-641&x-http-method-override=POST
```

But to no avail.

How can I get an array of objects into a URL so that service stack will be happy with it?!

I appreciate this is not the done thing but it's making explaining my end points infinitely easier with clickable example URLs

Comment: C'mon, stop abusing REST. Seems like you trying to use `POST` by means of `GET`. No wonder you having troubles. Guess what? It's just the beginning - think about support, API maturity, bewildered users. If I were you, I would stop right there and start using `POST`. The users of your API have hands and are hopefully intelligent, despite the fact it may sound silly. They will be able to craft a simple `POST` request. You can also help them by providing a simple and working example.

Comment: I did say this was purely for documentation!! this has nothing to do with production code and end users! This has nothing to do with REST purity and extreme REST opinions and religious beliefs. My REST service can behave perfectly RESTful and I can document it how I want. Using a legit question to prove how REST pure you are is a bit cheap IMO

Comment: I am referring to HTTP RFC standard. Where I agree we can debate about the purity of REST (and let's leave it along), you don't want to violate the standard. That was my point - a *common* standard that everyone understand.

Comment: Just to put this out there as an alternative approach to documentation: ServiceStack also supports Swagger, an HTML/JS interface, for interactive documentation of your API.

Comment: I have tried getting swagger set up but can't figure how to get it to see my api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSV](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format) to encode complex objects in the URL. This should work for your DTO:

```
model/listing?name=wayne&artists=[{id:artists-289,name:sample1},{id:artists-290,name:sample2}]&locationId=locations-641
```

You can programmatically create JSV from an arbitrary object using the `ToJsv` extension method in ServiceStack.Text.